# Dell XPS PC is Intermittently Shutting Down, Even in Safe Mode

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I have a slightly older Dell XPS 9910 (Intel Core i7-6700 @ 3.4 GHz) running Windows 10 (20H2). It has been intermittently shutting down. Since I could not discern a pattern I restarted in "safe mode with networking" to begin the diagnosis. It still did the same so I am thinking this may be a hardware issue. However, I am at a loss as to how to begin diagnosing which hardware this might be that is causing the problem.

What is the best way to proceed from here?

Comment: Get the Dell Hardware Diagnostic App for your machine and test all the hardware with that. Since the problem is intermittent you may need to run it several times.

Comment: Does it happen both when plugged in and on battery? Does it happen when idle and/ or under load? How often does it happen? I might try getting a Linux boot disk and do some stress testing (of CPU and memory)

Comment: Thanks John for the advice.  It turns out that it needs a new hard drive.